# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException

Tags: java, spring, api, hibernate, boot

I don't know why the error below occurs.

It is running normally on another computer with Spring boot application. When I run it on a new computer, it boots normally, but when I call the api, the following error message occurs.

What could be the problem? I'm not feeling well, so I'm asking for help.

```
2022-11-18 19:14:45,444 ERROR - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException] with root cause (DirectJDKLog.java: 175)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[?:?]
BuiltinClassLoader.java:582
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
ClassLoaders.java:178
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
ClassLoader.java:521
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:44
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
HQLQueryPlan.java:112
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
HQLQueryPlan.java:73
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
QueryPlanCache.java:162
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:788) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:788
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
CriteriaQueryImpl.java:314
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
CriteriaCompiler.java:165
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:751) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:751
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
Method.java:566
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

I expect the api to be called normally.

Comment: what is the tool you are using to build ? mvn grandle ant .....
or you just trying to run a jar file ?

Comment: the problem is that the jvm try to load the class, but this class cannot be found in your classpath, try to add the specified jar to your class path.

Comment: check that line log mentioned `DirectJDKLog.java: 175` , it can be relate to ide or jvm version.

Comment: I'm using gradle.. and antlr-2.7.7.jar already exist.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where to check what.

Comment: and i'm using visual studio code.